# VBA Highlight Cells multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba, highlight

Im trying to create a code within a spreadsheet that will highlight a separate range of cells (A28:D28) when 2 different conditions on cells E13="Country" and F13="State" are met, F13 has a validation dependent on the value on E13 which also has a data validation. So far I have this code, which I think makes no sense at all.

```
Set A = Range("E13")
    If Not Intersect(Target, A) Is Nothing Then
    If A = "Country" Then
        For Each A In Range("E13")
        If A.Offset(0, 1) = "State" Then
        A.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
        End If
    End If
End If
```

This code would be used for multiple combinations across multiple sections to highlight multiple ranges but I think I can manage to copy paste and change ranges, Im sorry to say my VBA skills are not that good.
All of this goes after a code that returns MsgBoxs when certain criteria is met on a separate set of ranges.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the very basic line of code to get the job done:

```
Sub temp()

    If Range("E13").Value = "Country" And Range("F13").Value = "State" Then Range("A28:D28").Interior.ColorIndex = 5

End Sub
```

Here is if you need the code to run with E13 changes:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E13")) Is Nothing Then
    If Range("E13").Value = "Country" And Range("F13").Value = "State" Then Range("A28:D28").Interior.ColorIndex = 5
    'Copy and past the line above with the other criteria you may need
End If

End Sub
```

How to clear the whole range of color before running the fill color and check whether E13 OR F13 changes:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E13:F13")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("A28:D38").Interior.Pattern = xlNone 'replace A28:D38 with your range 
    If Range("E13").Value = "Country" And Range("F13").Value = "State" Then Range("A28:D28").Interior.ColorIndex = 5
    'Copy and past the line above with the other criteria you may need
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Blake! Thank you, it works fine, but this may be a bit more tricky thank I explained or realized it would be, the code works too perfectly haha, what if i change either E13 or F13 to some other option? Currently what it does is highlight the second range but not clear the first, which makes perfect sense, I would rather not ask the user to clear all the contents before selecting a new option, is there any fix for this?

Comment: Anytime you need to get rid of the fill of a range, you can use this code:

Range("A28:D28").Interior.Pattern = xlNone

Just replace the range in that code with the range you are needing to have no fill with ;)

If you have a lot of cells you're dealing with, you could even specify the entire range at the start of your code and use this line of code to get rid of the fill on all the cells, then run the code (that's what I'd do). I edited my answer to reflect a sample of this

Comment: Let me know if I completely misunderstood what you were saying lol

Comment: Hi Blake, sorry about the delay, so the first part of the code will highlight A28:D28 when E13 and F13 meet certain criteria, which works just fine, now lets say that the I change the value of either of E13 or F13, that would make another set of cells (lets say A30:D30) to highlight since the criteria is different, and that also works just fine, problem is, when changing the valies of E13 or F13, the original highlighted range will stay yellow, is there any way to change this?

Comment: Sorry I didnt clarify before, it didnt occur to me that would happen.

Comment: Hello John, try my edited solution, the 3rd in the list ;) Let me know how that works for you!

Comment: yeah! thats just it! thank you!!! now to make it a bit more tricky, E13 and F13 are one of the possible options, you can also select E14, F14 or E15, F15, all those 3 are available inputs for the user and each one should highlight its own option on the tables below, by doing that code, it will make the last selection be blank,is there any solution to this one? Sorry Im piling you up with so many questions.